# why it is taking a lot of time to convert image via HTTP to video in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

Below is the ffmpeg i am using to convert images into videos but It is taking around 3 minutes to convert image to 5 second video.
If I run the command on Image present on a directory then it converts images to videos very swiftly.

can anyone tell what I am doing wrong ?

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/23/12/03/arch-5678549__340.jpg' -t 5 -vf scale=1280:780 output.mp4 

ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnpp --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/17/18/26/woman-6186493__340.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5538 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 511x340 [SAR 1:1 DAR 511:340], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x5580ac8e7c40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] using SAR=1034/1129
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2 AVX512
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] profile High, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] 264 - core 152 r2854 e9a5903 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2017 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj420p(pc), 1280x780 [SAR 19929:21760 DAR 511:340], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  100 fps=0.0 q=28.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:01.64 bitrate=   0.2kbits/frame=  125 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      90kB time=00:00:04.88 bitrate= 151.7kbits/s speed=6.79x    
video:88kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.618829%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] frame I:1     Avg QP:16.31  size: 75247
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] frame P:31    Avg QP:16.13  size:   314
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] frame B:93    Avg QP:31.33  size:    49
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] consecutive B-frames:  0.8%  0.0%  0.0% 99.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] mb I  I16..4: 10.6% 77.6% 11.8%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  2.5%  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:97.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.4%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.6%  L0: 8.3% L1:91.7% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] 8x8 transform intra:77.5% inter:98.7%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 88.4% 95.3% 79.5% inter: 0.1% 0.5% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] i16 v,h,dc,p:  2%  3%  0% 95%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 21% 18%  7%  6% 11% 10% 10%  8%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 24% 18%  7%  5% 16% 11%  9%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 33% 21% 22% 24%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] ref P L0: 85.7%  0.1% 13.2%  1.0%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] ref B L0: 53.6% 46.4%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] ref B L1: 92.8%  7.2%
[libx264 @ 0x5580ac186b40] kb/s:143.20
aman@aman:~/Desktop/a$ ffmpeg -loop 1 -i 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/17/18/26/woman-6186493__340.jpg' -t 5 -vf scale=1280:780 output.webm
ffmpeg version n4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-cuda --enable-cuda-sdk --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnpp --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, image2, from 'https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2021/04/17/18/26/woman-6186493__340.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5538 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg (Progressive), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 511x340 [SAR 1:1 DAR 511:340], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
File 'output.webm' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg (native) -> vp9 (libvpx-vp9))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 0x5630553879c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x563054cd2500] v1.7.0
[libvpx-vp9 @ 0x563054cd2500] Neither bitrate nor constrained quality specified, using default CRF of 32
Output #0, webm, to 'output.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp9 (libvpx-vp9), yuv420p, 1280x780 [SAR 19929:21760 DAR 511:340], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libvpx-vp9
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=   57 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:01.28 bitrate=   3.3kbits/sframe=  103 fps=102 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:03.12 bitrate=   1.3kbits/sframe=  125 fps= 85 q=0.0 Lsize=      51kB time=00:00:04.96 bitrate=  84.0kbits/s speed=3.37x    
video:50kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.571023%
```

Comment: So the regular ffmpeg command is fast, but it's slow in this code? Does the log from ffmpeg show anything unusual? Is ffmpeg the problem or the rest of the code?

Comment: @llogan actually when i use online url of image it takes alot of time but when i download the image an give path of that image it is done instantly. no there is nothing unusual on the log. maybe it is taking a lot of time due to site permission or something like this.

Comment: If you manually use ffmpeg in a terminal with the online url of the image is it also slow? Or only when executed via your code?

Comment: @llogan with online url it is slow. I will update it on post also.

Comment: So it seems that all of this code is in the way and is just noise. You should run ffmpeg manually in a terminal, show the command, and show the complete log.

Comment: @llogan I have added the command and full log on post.

Answer (score -1):

`ffmpeg` is making repeated GET requests. Example server log:

```
[20/Apr/2021:08:51:15 -0800] "GET /image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 206 36166
[20/Apr/2021:08:51:16 -0800] "GET /image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 206 36166
[20/Apr/2021:08:51:16 -0800] "GET /image.jpg HTTP/1.1" 206 36166
```

Simple solution is to use `curl`, `wget`, or similar to get the file before executing `ffmpeg`:

```
curl -L -o image.jpg https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2020/10/23/12/03/arch-5678549__340.jpg
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image.jpg -t 5 -vf scale=1280:780,format=yuv420p -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```